# How to disable Synaptics Touchpad from detecting finger on buttons area as a second finger for gesture

Tags: mouse, touchpad, synaptics, multi-touch, scrolling

So i'm using Xubuntu 22.04.3 (jammy) all up to date and would like to know how to disable a second finger detection that acts as scroll gesture on Synaptics touchpad (the red area in the illustration image should only act as the button when i actually press the button (i usually don't do tap clicks in this area).. so explaining the image, i always leave finger 1 on the red area to be ready for clicking (basically laying down the finger), and finger 2 for navigation so i move on the page with finger 2 and click with finger 1, because the way it is now, whenever i leave finger 1 on the button and finger 2 for moving on the page, it acts like a scrolling gesture and i don't want that to happen. For scrolling, the only area that i need to act as scrolling gesture is everything but the red area in the image:

[image: illustration image]

Also just for information, i do the same thing in Windows and it works just like i explained, i'm pretty new to Ubuntu and still learning so thanks in advance and sorry for any mistake, i didn't try anything yet because as i said i'm new to Ubuntu and didn't found anything that matches my problem

```
> xinput list
ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                    id=16

> xinput list-props "16"

Device 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (182):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (184): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (316): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (317):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (318):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (319):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (327):  123, 2974, 114, 2005
    Synaptics Finger (328): 1, 1, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (329):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (330):   165
    Synaptics Tap Durations (331):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (332):   1
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (333):  0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (334):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (335):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (336): -75, -75
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (337): 1, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (338):   1, 0
    Synaptics Move Speed (339): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.053305, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (340):    1
    Synaptics Locked Drags (341):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (342):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (343): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2
    Synaptics Click Action (344):   1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (345): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (346):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (347): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (348):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (349): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (350):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (351): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (352):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (353): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (354):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (355):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (356):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (357):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (358): 32, 31
    Synaptics Area (359):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Soft Button Areas (360):  1548, 0, 1737, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (361): 18, 18
    Device Product ID (309):    2, 14
    Device Node (308):  "/dev/input/event4"
```